# TypeError when trying to call functions in run

Tags: python, csv, typeerror

Edit; Thanks everyone! It's working now!

I'm trying to make a program that reads a csv file and calculates using that data. I have my `csv_reader` function and my `average_temperature` function working independently but I don't understand how to call them in the `run()` function.

I understand what the error means but I'm completely lost on how to fix it, but here's the closest I've gotten. It ends up with this error and then below it is the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 100, in <module>
    run()
  File "main.py", line 82, in run
    avgfile = average_temperature("Temperatures.csv", input)
  File "main.py", line 40, in average_temperature
    if filter in row[date_index]:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not builtin_function_or_method
```

Code:

```
import csv


date_index = 0
temp_index = 2


def csv_reader(file):
    lst = []
    with open("Temperatures.csv", 'r') as weather_file:
        weather_reader = csv.reader(weather_file)
        first_row = True
        for row in weather_reader:
            if first_row:
                first_row = False
                continue
            lst.append(row)
    return lst

def average_temperature(weather, filter):
    thefile = csv_reader("Temperatures.csv")
    sum = 0
    len = 0
    for row in thefile:
        if filter in row[date_index]:
            sum += float(row[temp_index])
            len += 1
    avg = sum / len
    return avg

def run():
    thefile = csv_reader("Temperatures.csv")
    avgfile = average_temperature("Temperatures.csv", input)

    print("{}".format(avgfile))

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: `avgfile = average_temperature("Temperatures.csv", input)` input is builtin function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `input` is the name of a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). I think what you need to do is *call* it and get a value to pass as the `filter` parameter to your `average_temperature()` function something like this:

```
def run():
    date_filter = input('What date? ')  # Get value from user.
    thefile = csv_reader("Temperatures.csv")
    avgfile = average_temperature("Temperatures.csv", date_filter)

    print("{}".format(avgfile))

    return
```

Comment: Also, given that `thefile` is never used and `average_temperature` opens `Temperatures.csv` anyway, you could drop the call to `csv_reader`. Or better yet, pass `thefile` to `average_temperature` (rewriting the function to accept a file-like object or iterable rather than a file name).